# Creating a line of best fit for time series using fittedvalues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create to create a linear and quadratic trend for my data (the log of the time series) but am getting a `KeyError` for the `result = sm.OLD(logelec[Y], logelec[X]).fit()` line.

```
elec = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shihanxie/Econ475/main/data/elec.csv')
elec.index = pd.date_range(start='1973-01-01', periods= elec.shape[0], freq='M')

start = '1973-01-01'
end = '2011-01-01' 
logelec = np.log(elec['elec'])
plt.plot(logelec[start:end])
ax = plt.gca()


logelec['constant'] = 1
logelec['trend'] = np.arange(logelec.shape[0])
X = ['constant', 'trend']
Y = ['logelec']
result = sm.OLS(logelec[Y],logelec[X]).fit()
result.model.data.xnames=['C', 'trend']


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax1)

y_fit = result.fittedvalues
ax1.plot(logelec, label = 'actual')
ax1.plot(y_fit, label = 'fitted')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Way too much unnecessary code; please limit your code to reproduce just the error, while still being runnable. As far as I can tell, you can easily remove all the plotting code.

Comment: Is `elec['elec']` a single column of the `elec` dataframe?

Comment: yes its the column that is being graphed

Comment: Be aware that `logelec['constant'] = 1` and `logelec['trend'] = np.arange(logelec.shape[0])` probably don't do what you intend to do. `logelec` is a Series, not a DataFrame. Print `logelec` just before the line with the `KeyError` to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`logelec = np.log(elec['elec'])` makes `logelec` a Series. Given the two subsequent assignments,

```
logelec['constant'] = 1
logelec['trend'] = np.arange(logelec.shape[0])
```

it looks like you probably intend for `logelec` to be a DataFrame, not a Series.

Try:

```
logelec = pd.DataFrame({'constant': 1, 'trend': np.arange(len(logelect),
                   'logelec': logelec})
```

instead of those two assignments (untested).